# Simulator crashes on verify Apple ID sign in

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, verification, apple-id

Does anyone know why my simulator would be crashing when I get the verification message after I correctly put in my email and password to sign in to my AppleID?

Simulator iPhone 8 iOS 13.5

Mac OS Big Sur 11.1 - Apple M1 Chip

1. Click next

[image]

2. App crashes

[image]

3. Still get the verification message on my Mac

[image]

This is what I get on the simulator logs

> Jan  5 19:38:51 Jacobs-MacBook-Air com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8538B5B8-C189-48BA-AC62-8A64B068D09D[10375] (UIKitApplication:com.apple.Preferences[11a4][rb-legacy][10534]): Service exited due to SIGTRAP | sent by exc handler[10534]

Comment: Getting the same issue on simulator 13.5. Any solution?

Comment: Nothing yet... still trying to figure it out

Comment: Not working on iOS 14.4, then I download 13.5, not working and then I download 13.9 (take 2 days to download), it's get corrupted. :(